# SanDisk 128GB Bootable USB not detected

Tags: usb-drive, bootable

I am trying to make a bootable live Caine OS on a SanDisk 128GB but the system does not detect the any bootable device except the HDD. I have a Huawaei Mate and I'm running Linux on it

I ran the next commands to create the bootable usb
`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdaX` to format with zeros the USB

Convert it into FAT32 `mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdaX`

Create the bootable usb with
`dd if='~/Desktop/caine11.0.iso' of='/dev/sdaX' bs=8M status=progress`

After this process I checked the USB and found that all the files are there.
Once I turn it off and on to run it I press F12 and the device is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when importing the image I was selecting the partition too. That's wrong.
The correct command is ```sudo dd bs=4M if=/media/{user}/159C483D3BEE15BA/caine11.0.iso of=/dev/sdc status=progress oflag=sync``

The of has no particion selected instead of `sdc1`just `sdc` (On my example)

The next link explains very well all this https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1394459-how-to-create-a-bootable-linux-usb-drive-in-terminal-on-command-line/

Answer (score 2):

You are blindly using answers from Internet. Take a look onto devices there.

First command you are zeroing `/dev/sda` device. Then formatting as fat32 device `/dev/sdc1`. Later using dd to write to `/dev/sdb1`.

This is total disaster and you may be only lucky enough not to destroy your current partitions on system.

In such cases after putting pendrive onto usb slot you should try `dmesg` to get info about which device has been inserted, and then use this device properly in your chain of commands.

Comment: I copy pasted wrongly the info as I was doing quite a lot of checks. But at the end discovered the update on the huawei bios apparently prevent from booting form USB... still checking for some options.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have identified your USB device correctly by using `lsblk`. I'll assume it's `/dev/sdb`. It's the USB disk device.

Now, most distributions will mount the disk partition by default. It'll be something like `/dev/sdb1`. Unmount this by doing -

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Write the image using -

```
sudo dd if=/home/ferpalma21/Desktop/caine11.0.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=8M
```

Make sure to turn on USB booting from your BIOS menu.